# How to find largest folder?

Tags: linux

How to find which folder in home directory is largest by the number of files? (excluding directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -type f -printf '%h\n'|uniq -c|sort -rn|head -1
```

You can substitute "head -<N>" for "head -1" to see the top <N>, or remove it altogether to see the whole list from most to least number of files

From "man find":

```
   -printf format
     .....
          %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last element).  If the file name contains no
                 slashes (since it is in the current directory) the %h specifier expands to ".".
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(cd $HOME && find . -type f) | grep '/.*/' | cut --delimiter=/ --field=1,2 \
 | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse \
 | head -1 | cut --delimiter=/ --field=2
```

i.e. print every file path in home directory, use only the first 2 directories level  (the first being `.`), skipping files at the top level, group and count the occurences, then sort, then take the first entry, and print the name of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply mean which directory has the greatest number of files, ignoreing their size, you can do

```
find ~/ -type d -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do 
        files=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 | wc -l); 
        echo -e "$files\t$dir"; 
    done | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

That, however, also counts subdirectories as "files". To count only files, use this one instead:

```
find ~/ -type d -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do 
        files=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type -f | wc -l); 
        echo -e "$files\t$dir"; 
    done | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score -4):

Use the

```
$ ls
```

command, or list directory contents. Try something like:

```
$ cd /your_directory
$ ls -lA
```

that should work. Check the

```
 man ls
```

to tweak it for exactly what you'd like to see.